# find common elements in two lists

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

i have two array lists of type CRVariable (hibernate class) and i want to find their common elements (intersection i guess).

Here is my CRVariable hibernate class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "imageviewer_crvariable")
public class CRVariable implements Serializable   {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "VarId")
    private Long varId;

    @Column(name = "VarName", unique=true)
    private String varName;

    @Column(name = "VarDescription")
    private String varDescription;

    private String state;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="crvariables")
    private Set<CRImageType> crimagetypes = new HashSet<CRImageType>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cRVariable")
    private Set<CRFormField> cRFormFields;
        ....
```

So i am trying to use the Collection#retainAll() method in the following way:

```
...
List<CRVariable> variablesForCurrentImageType = new ArrayList<CRVariable>();
variablesForCurrentImageType = getCRVariablesForImageType(mySelectedImages.get(k));
...
List<CRVariable> mySelectedVariables = Arrays.asList(selectedVariables);
...
Collection<CRVariable> colA1 = new ArrayList<CRVariable>();
colA1.addAll(mySelectedVariables);

Collection<CRVariable> colB1 = new ArrayList<CRVariable>();
colB1.addAll(variablesForCurrentImageType);
...
if(colA1.size()>colB1.size()){
    colA1.retainAll(colB1); //intersection
    System.out.println(">>>> INTERSECTION SIZE: " + colA1.size());
} else {
    colB1.retainAll(colA1); //intersection
    System.out.println(">>>> INTERSECTION SIZE: " + colB1.size()); 
}
...
```

but whichever combination if i try i always get colA1 or colB1 size of zero (0)!

any ideas on what i have been missing?

Comment: Have you overridden equals and hashcode correctly?

Comment: any help on that? i guess no!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not implementing equals() correctly.

The retainAll() method can't know automatically which objects are equal, so you'll have to provide that.

Comment: you mean in the CRVariable class? to implement a equals() property?

Comment: Yes. If they're JPA entities, you could just check that they're the same class and that their primary key matches. Provided that you're using entities that already have their primary keys set.

Comment: yes actually the issue comes from the fact that i have one primary have (VarId) and an additional unique key (VarName) ...